# max sum of two sums in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have table:

```
Bonus     Value

500       1400

1500       177

1800       453

1200       100

800       2500

200         50

780        740
```

I wanted to print the sum of column whichever is maximum.

I Tried Following:

```
select 
case when sum(bonus)>sum(Value) then sum(bonus) end
case when sum(Value)>sum(bonus) then sum(Value) end
from emp
```

But i had not got the result.

**Error:**

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'case'.
```

Comment: but with , it will gives me two columns i want only one column result, just the max sum between two columns

Comment: case when sum(bonus)>sum(Value) then sum(bonus) 
when sum(Value)>sum(bonus) then sum(Value) end

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect, `CASE` keyword goes only once:

```
select 
  case when sum(bonus)>sum(Value) then sum(bonus)
     else sum(Value) 
  end as MaxSum
from emp
```

Comment: @chetan i checked your testing condition. It regardless of high-low, it is returning me whatever is the equal value

Comment: If they are equal it doesn't matter which one is returned. `Sum(value)` in this example will be returned. Change `>` to `>=` if you want `Sum(bonus)` for some reason.

Comment: @NenadZivkovic I i know it doesnt mattered me. No need to put >= . Thanx

Answer (score 3):

Your `case` statement is wrong, try this one:

```
select case when sum(bonus)>sum(Value) then sum(bonus) else sum(Value) end
from emp
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
SELECT TOP (1) *
FROM
  ( SELECT SUM(Bonus) AS MaxSum, 'Bonus' AS SummedColumn FROM emp
    UNION
    SELECT SUM(Value), 'Value' FROM emp
  ) AS tmp
ORDER BY MaxSum DESC ;
```

Test at [SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/26332/4)

Comment: Corrected. I mistakenly thought this was for MySQL at first.